# Am I allowed to host an ASP.NET MVC website using Mono and mod_mono?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, mono

I heard somewhere that the MVC license prevents you from using it on non-microsoft technologies, which would prevent me from developing in mono and hosting in Linux.

Is this true?

Has anyone used it with mono?

Can anyone point me in the direction of the license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally you're not supposed to, at least while it's still in beta/ctp phase.  Technically, it's probably not that hard to get going.  See this:
[ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 on Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202430/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-on-mono/203784)

Comment: @joel does that change on RTM?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone with access to a license: don't get to use mvc myself right now.