# Mono feature complete

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Does Mono miss any functionality from .NET? If not, when will we see official MS recognition for it, like including Mono platforms in the Platforms section on MSDN?

It seems like they are seen as separate things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They *are* separate things - Mono is a competitor to .NET. I doubt very much that we'll ever see it being advertised on MSDN. Would you expect Microsoft to have an advert for a Linux distribution there? ;)

(And no, Mono [doesn't contain everything from .NET](http://mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Portability#Missing_Functionality).)

Comment: More specifically Mono is a Novell product. http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: Gah! Fie on you Jon Skeet and your god-like typing/linking abilities. I can't get any answers in today!!!! 8^D

Comment: They do however correct a few bugs that .Net hasn't fixed yet. :)

Comment: This FAQ page also has a nice overview of what Mono does and does not contain: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_General

Comment: Thanks Jon. I didn't know that. If Mono is a competitor, then who's gonna take care of the claimed platform-independence of .NET?

Comment: @Joan: What claimed platform independence is that? It's (largely) processor independent, but I don't think MS claims that it's platform independent. The CLI spec is (largely), but that's not the same thing... It's certainly not the same kind of selling point for .NET that it is for Java.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I see what you mean. I thought it was also advertised as platform independent in addition to processor independent. :)

Comment: @Iceheat: it works, but it's against the license terms at the moment.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202430/

Comment: If you're interested in mono, you may also want to follow this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/16929/miguel-de-icaza

Comment: I didn't know he was registered here. It's awesome!

Comment: You can also hear Miguel discussing this among other Mono topics on the Herding Code podcast (episodes 28 and 29): http://herdingcode.com/

Answer (score 3):

To see the status of anything in the Mono object model vs the .NET Framework you can go to [this](http://go-mono.com/status/) page...

Comment: I think someone is pushing an agenda. Jon's answer got at least 2 DVs and it is completely correct.

Comment: Thanks JPunyon. How do you see it's got 2 DV?

Comment: I know that it got 2 DV because of watching the vote changes. It is true that the pattern I saw could have been 1 DV and one detracted UV, but I suspect 2 DV is more likely.

Comment: Thanks EBGreen, I thought there is a place that shows the progress of votes, like the replies history.

Comment: After the bot runs behind the scenes it would be possible to go to the rep tab on Jon's profile and see how many UVs/DVs the answer got.

Comment: @EBGreen - Actually...you would be able to do that...but he's already maxed out for today...so all you see is the 15 for acceptance...

Answer (score 3):

[MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) is a useful tool for examining your assemblies and reporting on any potential issues (e.g., not implemented methods).

There are a couple of things to be aware of with Mono. Despite a good report from MoMA, we've run into bugs (including regressions in the new 2.2 release) as you would expect. You do have the source and I really recommend being able to build Mono (in particular the managed part which compiles the libraries). Be sure to push bug reports via the public bugzilla for Mono.

Also, be aware of dependencies on third party libraries. Thorough testing is a must. For example, we tried using xUnit.net with mono and it mostly worked well. However, it uses an ugly reflection hack to set the value of a private member variable (in the Exception class). Of course, something like this is bound to cause runtime issues. Once again, source code to the rescue as xUnit.net is OpenSource.