# ASP.NET mvc on mono 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I am having a trouble. I am trying to run asp.net mvc 1.0 on mono 2.2.I have copied the system.web.mvc.dll to bin directory. I have done HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/Home/Index");. Still I am having te error:

Server Error in '/' Application The incoming request does not match any route

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

> System.Web.HttpException: The incoming request does not match any route at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) [0x00000] at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext httpContext) [0x00000] at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] at MvcApplication4._Default.Page_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive () [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoad () [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData () [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000] at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000]

Version information: Mono Version: 2.0.50727.1433; ASP.NET Version: 2.0.50727.1433

Comment: Last I heard, the asp.net-mvc license did not allow use with mono.  Doesn't mean it won't work or that they haven't changed it (this was 6 months ago), but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: The license that shipped with the final version of MVC no longer has this restriction (that I can find).

Comment: So, has anyone been able to run asp.net mvc on mono? I am also interested in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally managed to get it running. It seems that ASP.NET 3.5 MVC applications work just fine unmodified with the latest mono from svn(they do NOT on mono 2.2).
Detailed instructions for compiling it are here: http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_SVN

Obviously, you need to copy the System.Web.Mvc.dll to the bin/ subdirectory of your application.

In case anyone needs Mono and xsp on 32bit Linux, here is my build: http://www.speedyshare.com/283727620.html

UPDATE: The 2.4 release is out, go get it!

Another UPDATE: 2.6.1 is the latest release as of 3/15/2010

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202430) question, it will work with 2.4. I'm very much of the belief that it will not work with anything else than that, although 2.2 does have coverage of the routing in .NET 3.5 SP1...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "is it plugged in" question - did you move over your `Global.asax` file?  The #1 cause for the error you are seeing is a missing `Global.asax` as that file contains all your routes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't change anything in my global.asax file. Using .net it runs perfectly. This error happens in case I use mono.