# What is the equivalent to .net MVC in linux dev environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux

I have been a .net developer for many years and have recently become interested in developing a web app on Linux rather than Microsoft Windows.

What I particularly like about MVC is how easy you can get up a functioning project (+productivity) and also the `Code-First` approach (Entity Framework 4.1), which allows a database to be built on the fly during the development.

So I was wondering is there a supported framework like this on Linux, which you could recommend to me? And in what language is it?

Many Thanks,

Comment: May be Mono project (http://www.mono-project.com/)?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300975/what-are-the-available-mvc-web-frameworks-in-the-linux-world

Comment: @Aakash, that question was asked in 2009. MVC was back then not as advanced as it is today. I would like to know the options of what's available today. Thanks

Comment: @Kave MVC is over 30 years old. It is quite mature and stable. It is a design pattern developed in 1979 by Trygve Reenskaug, then working on Smalltalk at Xerox PARC.MVC is essentially a design pattern/architectural pattern than can be used in any language really. MS,Java and so on just provide pre built frameworks to this pattern. There is nothing stopping you from implementing MVC in even assembler though I suspect it would be more pleasant to chew your wrists off.

Comment: @Namphibian, apologies, I meant .net MVC, which was version 1.0 in 2009 and not as impressive as it is today.

Comment: @Kave no problem. MVC is the design pattern .net MVC is the implementation. I would suggest Mono and Java for now. Once you get into it there is a LOAD of other frameworks to use. Some easy some not so easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct that there are many options and there is no one answer to this.  As an experienced .NET developer I found learning Python was very straight forward. There are many similarities of concepts.

I also researched both Djando and Pyramid as Web Python frameworks and found the former much easier to use.  Django is in a way very similar to MVC .NET. It also includes an ORM mapper out of the box that does exactly what Entity Framework 4.1+ Code-First approach does.

In total I find using Django on Linux partially simpler and more productive than MVC .NET.

I am choosing this as an answer, not because other responses here are wrong, but because maybe other .NET converts might google for this question and like to hear the experience of a fellow .NET developer. ;)

Comment: As a fellow .NET dev googling for this question: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try a new language consider for example

- Spring Framework MVC - JAVA http://www.springsource.org/
- Zend MVC - PHP http://framework.zend.com
- Rails - Ruby*  http://rubyonrails.org/

There are many others too...

Answer (score 1):

Mvc is a development methodology originating in the 1970's.  So it is implemented in a lot of different languages. Java for example has several mvc frameworks that pre date .net by some years. I would suggest that you look at the following Mono, Java and I am sure php has a mvc framework. Mono is basically .net on Linux. Not sure how mature the project is. Java on Linux is by far a more pleasant experience than Java on windows and I would recommend that you also look at this. Java has got a entity framework of sorts called JPA. Just a heads up some of the learning curves are steep but well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [mono](http://mono-project.com) , [here](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_ASP.NET) is what it support.

In my memory that it support asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0):

node.js for the server and EXTJS for the presentation