# ASP.NET MVC on Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

what steps should I perform in order to run asp.net mvc 1.0 web application on mono?

Comment: Previous question for Preview 5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202430/aspnet-mvc-preview-5-on-mono I'd assume that's the same result with the released version.

Answer (score 1):

It requires the same steps as for 3.0.
minus

```
System.Web.Razor.dll 
System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll
```

But why do you even want to run a 1.0 application, when 4.0 works already ?

Here: 
[Does the Razor View Engine work for Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono/6317712#6317712)