# Developing ASP.NET MVC using MonoDevelop on MAC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, monodevelop, xsp

I am developing a web app using ASP.NET MVC 2.0 in MonoDevelop. I have latest Mono 2.10 and MonoDevelop 2.4.2 and I am running them on Mac.

According to mono’s release notes, it should support ASP.NET MVC 2.0. However, I found MonoDevelop’s project templates still only support ASP.NET MVC 1.0. So I had to create MVC project from MonoDevelop and remove system.web.mvc 1.0.0.0 from reference and add system.web.mvc 2.0.0.0 back in. I can write and compile code OK and MonoDevelop does provide intellisense for methods only exist in MVC 2.0 from both C# and aspx file. However, when I trying to run it from MonoDevelop, I had Compilation error complaining ”<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name) %>” as LabelFor method cannot be recognized .

MonoDevelop uses XSP as its testing web server. I am not sure how it configured as I didn’t install it myself. I think it was installed as part of MonoDevelop. My guess is XSP somehow still uses MVC 1.0 but I can't prove it as I couldn’t even find where it is installed.

Could anyone help me out please?

Update:
I have been suspecting web.config too. Here are how they look like now:
web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

web.config under views

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
            namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
        <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up an ASP.NET project for ASP.NET MVC requires changing and adding a load of settings in web.config. The project template in MD is for ASP.NET MVC 1.0, not ASP.NET MVC 2, so you're probably missing some of the necessary settings, maybe a namespace import.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have put web.config in my question. Is there anything look like suspicious to you?

Comment: Hmm, that all looks correct. Maybe it is somehow still loading the wrong dll. Try running the debugger - it prints out a list of all the assemblies it's loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have this running with two of my current projects on MacOS X. There were only three steps I needed to make sure were done, they are as follows:

- Upgrade the version on all references in both the inner (views) web config and the outter(app) [you've done this].
- Dereference System.Web.MVC 1.0.0.0 & Reference 2.0.0.0 for the project
- Ensure you don't have 1.0.0.0 binaries in your bin path, the public key does not change

Answer (score 0):

I've done a downloadable zip file of a project template for Asp.Net MVC 4 which builds and runs on/in Mono/Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop on Mac & Linux at http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1319/run-asp-net-mvc4-on-mono-monodevelop-on-mac-the-c-template-project.
I should add that a lot of the issue resolution came from [Does the Razor View Engine work for Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono)