# Is it possible to use Razor 2.0 view engine under mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mono

I was insterested in Razor 2.0's [condition attributes](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/what%27s-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2#Changes_for_the_Beta_Version) feature, so I tried to port Razor 2.0 to my MVC3 apps. I followed [this link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-razor-v2-aspnet-mvc-3) and successfully run my simple app (with one `HomeController`, one `Index` action and one ***~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml** view) on **Windows with ASP.NET**.

But when I deployed my app on mono runtime on Ubuntu, it fails to run and continues to report an error of **Cannot find view**:

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

I googled for this error, most of the articles says it is a problem of view compiling, so I thought it is caused by mono cannot properly use the new Razor engine's compiler to compile **Index.cshtml**.

I then switched my app back to Razor 1.0 and everythings works fine under mono, so is it really a problem that mono cannot run Razor 2.0? or is there any quick solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of mono? You may try the trunk as it contains the open sourced official ASP.NET code: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Mar-28.html

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'm currently using mono 2.10 installed from the `apt-get` command line of Ubuntu, I may take a look at the trunk source. However razor2.0 itself is a beta version of ASP.NET, I'm wondering if it is possible to port at the source level, anyway this is a good change, thanks.

Comment: Seems like it works for Mono 2.10.2+

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono

Answer (score 4):

Razor pages worked with Mono, in theory, with version 2.10.x series, but you had to bundle Microsoft's assemblies with it into your Linux box.

Since [Mono 2.11.1](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-2-11-1-is-out-td4575466.html), these assemblies are now bundled by default in Mono, because Microsoft open sourced Razor recently (on [March 2012](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Mar-28.html)).

Hence, if I were you I would try Mono 2.11.3 to see if the problem is already fixed upstream. If not, please file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ with a standalone testcase to reproduce it, and link to the bug from here.

Comment: Have you been through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497900/how-to-use-url-action-in-mono) kind of issue?