# Mono 2.10 Reflection error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to deploy an ASP MVC 3 (.NET Framework 4.0) application to ubuntu 12.04 with Mono. This is the current version I have of Mono installed:

> Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
>   Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
>       TLS:           __thread
>       SIGSEGV:       altstack
>       Notifications: epoll
>       Architecture:  amd64
>       Disabled:      none
>       Misc:          softdebug 
>       LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
>       GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)

In order to know exactly where the code was breaking I removed the ASP project and run my method from a console application so I could debug into. I found this is the method where my code is breaking:

```
    public IEnumerable<Type> loadClassAttributes<TAttribute>() where TAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        return from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
               from t in a.GetTypes()
               where t.IsDefined(typeof(TAttribute), false)
               select t;
    }
```

And this is the error stack Mono Developer is showing:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator2B`3[[System.Reflection.Assembly, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[<>__AnonType1`2[[System.Reflection.Assembly, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Type, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], TBL.Common.Dal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext ()

When I ran this same application from ASP MVC using XSP4 this is the screenshot my browser displays

[image]

I have been doing .NET development for years, but I am really newbie to Mono. I wonder if someone else has gone into this issue and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Added log output

Mono: gc took 31 usecs
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0x20fc8c0] -> /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll[0x20fbb90]: 2
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: /usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/mscorlib.dll.config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'.
Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0x20fc8c0] added to domain alogimex.test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/etc/mono/config'.
Mono: Config attempting to parse: '/home/mleyzaola/.mono/config'.
Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'alogimex.test.exe'.
Mono: Image addref alogimex.test[0x21791f0] -> /home/mleyzaola/net/alogimex.mono/alogimex.mono.solution/alogimex.test/bin/Debug/alogimex.test.exe[0x20fa980]: 3
Mono: Assembly alogimex.test[0x21791f0] added to domain alogimex.test.exe, ref_count=1
Mono: AOT failed to load AOT module /home/mleyzaola/net/alogimex.mono/alogimex.mono.solution/alogimex.test/bin/Debug/alogimex.test.exe.so: /home/mleyzaola/net/alogimex.mono/alogimex.mono.solution/alogimex.test/bin/Debug/alogimex.test.exe.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, do you think upgrading to 3.x would solve the issue? Have you got any reference well known to work fine for this?

Comment: Reading the log it looks like it cannot find mscorlib.dll file although I have double checked it is there actually. Arg!!!

Comment: Here is the full log file: http://pastebin.com/icE60gfe

Comment: mono 2.10 is obsolete, last stable version is 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels weird to do something, fix it and don't have a clue what was wrong initially. However this was fixed with the upgrade on Mono Develop 3.1

In case someone else happens to have this issue, the answer is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16093182/917268