# Monodevelop broken on Fedora?

Tags: mono, gtk, monodevelop, glib, gtk#

I have a little project that uses mono gtk-sharp, that I build under monodevelop on Fedora and Xamarin on Windows. I wanted to try a clean build, but now I get the following error in Fedora if i try an debug build:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'GLib.IgnoreClassInitializersAttribute' from assembly 'gtk-sharp'.
at AudioCuesheetEditor.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x003e1] in /media/Auslagerung/Projekte/AudioCuesheetEditor/src/AudioCuesheetEditor/MainClass.cs:120
```

If I build a "Release" build, everything works fine. But why does the debug build fail? I have installed all needed libraries. The project src is here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/p/audiocuesheet/code/HEAD/tree/
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance ;).

Comment: Just a WAG (I don't know much about mono or .net), but did you install the debuginfo package for gtk-sharp?  `yum install gtk-sharp2-debuginfo`.

Comment: There is no package gtk-sharp2-debuginfo says yum. I just tried it on my other fedora machine, there the debug build works perfect with the same fedora version, fully updated and the project not modified.

Comment: Try `debuginfo-install gtk-sharp2`.  Works for me on F20.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Why do I need the debuginfo? Is there a backround?

Comment: Helped as in it now works (in which case I should probably convert the comment to an answer), or you were just able to install the debuginfo package successfully?  Debugging information adds a significant amount of bloat to the object code, so most Linux distributions ship the stripped code for most users and separate packages containing the debugging symbols for those who need them.

Comment: I was able to install the debuginfo package with your help ;).

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I've updated to fedora 20 and now I'm having the same problem with installed debuginfos. So, what should I do?

Comment: The 2.8.8.4 version of monodevelop shipped with Fedora is severely outdated, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17949042/23118 for a 4.2.3 version packed as monodevelop-opt.