# Using Git via MonoDevelop 3: Can't push commits, System.NullReferenceException

Tags: git, version-control, mono, monodevelop, nullreferenceexception

So I'm using MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2, on Ubuntu 13.04, to make a game in Haxe.  The project and programming language aren't relevant, though.  No, I'm having problems with MonoDevelop's Git integration.

I made the commits for the relevant files.  Fine.  But when I push them, I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Sharpen.HttpURLConnection.GetResponseCode () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NGit.Util.HttpSupport.Response (Sharpen.HttpURLConnection c) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NGit.Transport.TransportHttp.Connect (System.String service) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NGit.Transport.TransportHttp.OpenPush () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NGit.Transport.PushProcess.Execute (NGit.ProgressMonitor monitor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NGit.Transport.Transport.Push (NGit.ProgressMonitor monitor, ICollection`1 toPush) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitRepository.Push (IProgressMonitor monitor, System.String remote, System.String remoteBranch) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitService+<Push>c__AnonStorey13.<>m__20 (System.Object ) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The commits I'm trying to push remove some files and edit others, but don't add any.

Any tips?

Comment: yes, your monodevelop version is ancient, upgrade to 4.x

Comment: There's no `.deb` package available for Ubuntu 13.04 yet.  I could compile from source, but I'm worried I'd break something.  (The version I have now is from the official Ubuntu repos.)

Comment: you can compile from source and run that version without installing, via "make run", that way you cannot break anything

Comment: Crap, I need the newest version of Mono, which is newer than what Ubuntu's repos offers...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365158/installing-mono-3-0/13384233#13384233