# Install latest version of mono xsp4 on ubuntu to support asp.net 4.5

Tags: ubuntu, mono, apt, xsp, xsp4

i have to port an asp.net 4.5 website to mono 2.10.8.1 on an ubuntu machine.

Does xsp4 support asp.net 4.5 yet or should i build my original website in 4.0 for the time being?

Also how do i get the latest version and install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET 4.5 is not supported in Mono 2.x, upgrade to Mono 3.x.

You have a guide here: [Installing Mono 3.x in Ubuntu/Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365158/installing-mono-3-0)