# No package 'mono' found when installing XSP

Tags: linux, nginx, mono, centos, xsp

I am trying to get Mono working on nginx with fastCGI.

I have done a fresh install of CentOS 6, and performed all the updates. I then installed nginx, and opened up the firewalls I needed. I can now see the simple HTML page from nginx without a problem.

I then followed this tutorial for installing Mono via Git :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424880/221456

libgdiplus installed fine
mono installed fine
xsp, when I run autogen (with the prefix), gives me this error :

> checking for MONO_MODULE... configure: error: Package requirements
>   (mono >= 2.10.0) were not met:
>
> No package 'mono' found

I did a bit of searching, and the only thing I could find was to run this command :

> export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Which I have tried, however I still get the exact same error message.

What am I missing?

Comment: run this command and tell us what it prints: `which mono`

Comment: I get this : /usr/bin/mono

Comment: and what does `/usr/bin/mono --version` print?

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 3.3.0 (master/b2cc26a Mon Aug 26 16:04:00 CDT 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen

Comment: does the file `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/mono.pc` exist? also, tell us what does the file config.log have at the end (generated by autogen.sh)

Comment: The file exists, however the config.log is quite long, is there anything specific you wanted to see, or should I upload the content to a pastebin?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36364/discussion-between-justinn-and-knocte)

Comment: I said *the end of config.log*

Comment: sorry, but the end didn't seem to reveal much information, so I thought perhaps you needed something more. The last line is "configure: exit 1"

Comment: well, I meant something more than 1 line, how about 8?

Comment: Again, I don't think they're of much use, but here they are: #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
#define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
 
configure: exit 1
 
The full log can be seen here though (it's not too big) http://pastebin.com/dx4NmHiV

Comment: this is weird, pastebin the content of mono.pc?

Comment: Could it possibly be down to me running 64 bit Linux and this assumes everybody is 32 bit? Content of mono.pc http://pastebin.com/tSZWRytZ

Comment: I have just tried this all on a 32 bit OS install, exact same steps and it just works perfectly fine! So I would guess that the issue is with 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the variable

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

the correct is

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
```

because you compile with the with the prefix. /usr

Comment: Note to others, my package was located under `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.4.0/lib/pkgconfig/‌​`