# Missing Method exception mono

Tags: c#, mono, system.net, missingmethod

I want to execute my C# app, compiled in Windows, on my Ubuntu Server.

I am using the .Net Framework version 4.5 (can't change it cause of some 3rd party api's).

I have the most actual Mono version (2.10.8) for Ubuntu installed. My Application is compiled with VisualStudio 2012 on the Windows OS (7).

I am trying to make some Post requests to other websites and parse data. Here is the code which creates the Requests (which works on windows perfectly):

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri.AbsoluteUri);

req.UserAgent = this.UserAgent;
req.CookieContainer = this.Cookies;
req.Referer = this.Location;
req.Host = uri.Host;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

And the error i am getting from Mono comes here:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Date'.
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.GetPostWebRequest (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.Post (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.Post (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.networks.components.MyClass.MyMethod() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Date'.
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.GetPostWebRequest (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.Post (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 headers) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.http.HttpBrowser.Post (System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 postdata) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.networks.components.MyClass.MyMethod() [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at manager.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I googled for 2 days now and can't find a solution. :(

UPDATE:

The attributes set_Date AND set_host are currently not Implemented at Mono. (I upgraded my Version to 3.x)

Comment: Mono and .NET are not 100% compatible. If you build your program for .NET, it won't necessarily run on Mono.

Comment: Yeah, but mono documentation says that System.Net should be completly implemented. And if not, is there any workaround ?

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Net
The first spot. And if i missed it isn't, is the no workaround ?

Comment: Last updated 604 days ago. Are you sure it's the *right version* of the code?

Comment: In any case, mono is definitely not 100% compatible with .NET. Bits and pieces might be, but to expect your code to work is basically just hoping for the best. The only real solution here is to compile your code for mono.

Comment: Can i precompile for mono on windows already?

Comment: You must use Mono 3.2.* as only that version has .NET 4.5 profile. Mono 2.* has been obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4.5 is not supported in Mono 2.x, upgrade to Mono 3.x.

You have a guide here: [Installing Mono 3.x in Ubuntu/Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365158/installing-mono-3-0)

Comment: post the whole NotImplementedException with the stacktrace