# How can I get an ASP.NET MVC site running on Mono?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, nginx, mono, mod-mono

I've found plenty of questions / blog posts about this, but I have not seen a repeatable recipe for getting an MVC site running on Mono. Nor have I been able to, after many hours of attempts, been able to get an MVC site to run on Mono.

I can spin up whatever version of whatever distribution is required, and can use either MVC3 or MVC4. I would prefer to use nginx, but can use mod_mono as well. I can build from source or use packages.

Can anyone give a step-by-step on getting MVC to run on Mono?

**Example Error**

This is what I get when I try to run a barebones app on fastcgi or xsp:

```
Missing method .ctor in assembly 
/tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/eaee30a1/assembly/shadow/bef1c25f
/a2978c47_1c664e18_00000001/System.Web.Providers.dll, 
type System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmRelationshipAttribute

Can't find custom attr constructor image: 
/tmp/root-temp-aspnet-0/eaee30a1/assembly/shadow/bef1c25f
/a2978c47_1c664e18_00000001/System.Web.Providers.dll mtoken: 0x0a000012
```

Comment: See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono/6317712#6317712

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. Use MonoDevelop IDE http://monodevelop.com/.

Check this page http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/06/get-mvc3-razor-running-on-mono/

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, it didn't help. See the above error.